# CTRL-C not working when running delayed_job (Windows)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

ok silly question but driving me crazy. I am using ruby 1.9.3 and delayed_job gem, when I run jobs from command prompt with:

```
rake jobs:work
```

I cannot stop them with CTRL-C. I have to close command prompt window. Has anybody had this problem by any chance?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using windows if **CTRL+C** does not work. You can use **CTRL + BREAK**